# How do I convert Integers to Floats or doubles in Lua?

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

I used *Logitechs LUA implementation* to write a simple *no recoil script*.

I want to fine tune the ***NR Variable*** by converting it to a double and using decimals.

Whenever I try to do this,the console puts out

```
[string "LuaVM"]:45: bad argument #2 to 'OutputLogMessage' (number has no integer representation) Line Number:1
```

And the Script stops working if decimal numbers are inserted. I don´t really know how I can do the conversion even after looking into the documents.

```
--General--
UP = 13                     -- to increase NoRecoil strength, toggle Modify to change RapidFire strenght
DOWN = 12                   -- to reduce NoRecoil strength, toggle Modify to change RapidFire strenght
--NoRecoil
NR = 4                        -- distance to pull down, (default) recoil reduction
HorizontalRecoilModifier=0    -- unused, is for left right recoil     
Sleep_ = 10                    -- delay between pull down, less for smoother
--BINDS--   
--General--                 
UP = 13                     -- to increase NoRecoil strength, + Modify to increase RapidFireNoRecoil
DOWN = 12                   -- to reduce     
--NoRecoil                                     
RC = 3                        -- right click, when you press RC and LC it pulls down
LC = 1                        -- Left click, key boud to shoot ingame

--FUNCTIONS--                       
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);   -- to capture primary (1) klick
OutputDebugMessage("Profil Aktiv")
function NoRecoil()
    repeat
    MoveMouseRelative(0,NR)
    Sleep(Sleep_)
until not IsMouseButtonPressed(LC)
end
--NoRecoilModify
function Add()
    NR=NR+1     
    if (NR>10) then
        NR=0
    end         
    OutputLogMessage("NR %d\n", NR)
    OutputDebugMessage("NR %d\n", NR)
end
function Reduce()
    NR=NR-1     
    if (NR<0) then
        NR=10
    end
    OutputLogMessage("NR %d\n", NR)
    OutputDebugMessage("NR %d\n", NR)
end
--increaseAndReduce
function OnEvent(event, arg)   

    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == UP) then
        Add()
    end
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == DOWN) then
        Reduce()
    end
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)then                               
        repeat
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(LC)  then
                NoRecoil()
            end
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(RC)
    end
end
```

*Please keep in mind this is my first serious attempt at understanding LUA for some shenanigans, I am currently learning Java at my Uni and this is my fourth week of actual coding.*

Comment: Your issue is likely with the `%d` in your messages. `%d` is expecting an integer. Try `%f` instead?

Comment: @NickSlash This was actually everything I needed to do. I followed the Logitech guide, which wasn´t really comprehensive and all the other lua specifics kinda threw me off. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The format placeholder `%d` specifically denotes an integer. Use `%f` or any other floating point placeholder as explained in a documentation for `sprintf` (the underlying implementation of string formatting in Lua), e.g.
https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/man-pages/sprintf.3.en

Comment: Thanks! However I have one more question. The **MoveMouseRelative** Function only registers changes made in Whole numbers. How would I implement decimal changes correctly?

Comment: If that function doesn't accept floats, or ignores their decimals, then there is nothing you can do, short of asking Logitech to implement that.

Comment: @AlanBourne - `MoveMouseRelative` expects distance in pixels.  It is impossible to move cursor fractional amount of pixels.